# Parametric test if underlying assumption is gamma distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, gamma-distribution

I'm trying to concudt an A/B test where I want to compare the mean of two groups of customer spendings and decide whether they are significant or not. I have a dataset of 10 000 customers and their total spendings within a period of time, however around 8500 of these are zero. So the histogram looks like this for the raw data:

[image]

Where the x-axis is the customer spending. A quick instinct was to remove the 0 frequencies and the rightmost outliers, then I got this

[image]

where i've fitted a gamma distribution with parameters $a=1.909$ and $b=662.039$.

Questions:

1. It seems wrong to just remove the 0 at the start since the number of customers that don't purchase (i.e don't respond to a campaign or e-mail) is important to distinguish between the groups.
2. Assuming that the first point above is somehow OK to do, then I can assume gamma distribution and in that case, what statistical test can I apply to do the test?
3. Would it maybe be better to do a non-parametric test instead?

Comment: Re 1.  Use a zero inflated distribution
Re 2 and 3: If you care about a mean comparison, why bother with fitting a gamma distribution.  Just do a non parametric mean comparison ( permutation test?).  Last but not least: for a zero inflated distribution like this and the use case I m wondering whether the mean is really of interest or rather looking at quantiles is more relevant.  E.g. which group is more likely to spend more than $x ?

Comment: @GeorgM.Goerg - Thanks for your answer. Let's assume I'd instead look at quantiles, what method/test should I use then?

Comment: Correct, it is wrong to remove the zeros.  Use a semiparametric ordinal model with no binning of Y.  This has far fewer assumptions than a zero inflated parametric model which often cannot zero inflate enough.

Comment: @FrankHarrell - Thanks, I've never heard of this test. Do you have any further information or link on how it's conducted?

Comment: Start with the nonparametrics chapter in [BBR](https://hbiostat.org/bbr) then look at [RMS course notes](https://hbiostat.org/rms).

Comment: You have to use a zero-inflated model.

Comment: @AminShn - Do you have any use case example of implementation? Or any theory you can link to?

Comment: @Parseval you can still do a permutation test on (empirical )quantiles or - what seems more interesting for CLV -  p(value > cutoff) based on gamma model

Comment: @FrankHarrell How can a zero-inflated model not zero-inflate enough?  By construction it models the zero inflation part with a single parameter (p0) which when estimated via MLE, will match exactly the inflation you see in data. If anything, it might overfit and do too much zero inflation for out of sample data.

Comment: You are quite right.  Thanks for the correction.  I still thing that a parametric model may not fit well enough in many cases .

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at ["A Deep Probabilistic Model for Customer Lifetime Value Prediction"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.07753.pdf) which provides a training algorithm to learn CLV from high dimensional feature spaces using zero-inflated log-normals (ZILN).  Changing this to a zero-inflated Gamma distribution is a trivial exercise.

In particular, they explain why looking at mean squared error (and hence means) is a sub-optimal way to look at this type of problem, because it a) does not work well with the high number of zeros; and b) ignores the right skew in the data.

I would suggest to look at the underlying business problem again and see if a quantile based comparison is more relevant for decision makers. I suspect that decision makers will care about two things: churn rate and long term life time value for returning customers.  The ZILN model allows you to estimate both (and get confidence [or posterior] intervals for both).

Last but not least, if you still want mean comparisons, then you can always compute the mean of the zero inflated log normal based on parameter estimates.

Comment: M.Goerg - Well, what the decisionmakers want to know is the following: If we do certain campaigns and treat a group of customers in a way (group A) and not treat another group of customers at all (group B), will there be any difference in spending between the groups? I don't quite understand how churn rate and LTV comes into play here. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Spending over what time horizon?  Do they consider any downstream effects on spending like loyalty or available budget?  e.g., if I target 1000 customers in campaign A vs campaign B, and in campaign A 100% buy for 10 dollars each; in campaign B 10% buy with 100 dollars each the total spend is the same, but you attracted quite a different set of people to your website with different likely different LTV